# How to choose the highest value based on multiple columns?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this table:
[Performance Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjVxh.png)

When the same encounter is recorded I need to get the highest performance. A MAX function will do, but I need to do an AVERAGE function for all the encounters dynamically.

I tried this:
`=AVERAGEIFS(Player[Player.performance],Player[Player.difficulty],"=4")` but gives me the average of all encounters with the Spec 3 and not always the Spec 3 has the highest performance. So I need to do the average for all encounters choosing the highest performance when a given encounter is recorded more than once. I cant figure out.

Any help?

Comment: It's very good that you provide an example of something you tried to solve your problem. But I'm confused by why you say it didn't work. The AVERAGEIFS function is designed to give an average based on certain criteria being met. You seem to say your formula didn't work because Spec 3 doesn't always have the highest performance -- but, if that's so, why did you include Spec 3 among the criteria in your formula? Besides that point, I'm also unable to understand what you're asking. Please try giving an example of your desired result for a specific case.

Comment: You are right. The spec criteria isnt important. I copy/pasted from a partial solution. Answering your question: I need to do the AVERAGE performance from the highest performances from each encounter. So, if I have the same encounter recorded more than once, only the highest performance goes into the AVERAGE, skipping the others values.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I can almost guarantee you will get a good response if you provide the example I mentioned at the end of my comment, and if you do so with actual data rather than an image.  That way those who provide the help can copy/paste your example.

Comment: This https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsaNMurFRzRtgk6SRlW4XCYpTKc8 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this formula into `E2`, but then be sure to hold down `ctrl-shift` as you click `Enter` (this makes it an array formula)

```
=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$16=A2,$D$2:$D$16))
```

Then drag this formula down. Now you have the maximum for each performance. To remove duplicates, select column A and use the advanced filter as shown in the animated .gif Here's a [link to a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uJI_lcFkk50) to learn more

[image]

Comment: Hey Tony. So, on your gif, column C have the same value always, but now I have 3 new values, 1, 3 and 5. So that column can be 1, 3, 4 and 5. Your solution still work if I'm looking the highest performance regardless difficulty (columnn C). So, the solution seemed simple enough. To use the AND function with the IF like:
`=MAX(IF(AND($A$2:$A$16=A2,$C$2:$C$16=4),$D$2:$D$16))`
and press `crtl+shift+enter` but didnt worked. Im always getting `#VALUE!` or `zeros`. What im doing wrong?

Comment: Edit: As the size of the table can change over time, I'm doing this:`=MAX(IF(AND([Player.encounter]=A2,[Player.difficulty]=4),[Player.performance]))`

Comment: Solved. I cant use an AND function that way because is an Array Formula, I needed nested IF with the second criteria. So `=MAX(IF([Player.encounter]=A2,IF([Player.difficulty]=4,[Player.performance])))` =D